# Angular From Submit after an ajax call success

Tags: angularjs, forms, formvalidation-plugin

In one of my angular JS application, I would likes to validate and submit a form after an ajax call ( if it returns 1 )

**So currently my form submission looks like**

```
$scope.formSubmit=function(form,$event){
        form.$submitted = true;
        if(form.$valid==false){
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
```

My AJAX Code part is

```
$scope.checkLogin=function(){
    var url=$('#site').val()+'/ajax/checkLogin/'+Math.random();
    return $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      async:   false,
      cache:   false,
      url     : url,
      data: {},
      headers : { 'Accept' : 'application/json' , 'Pragma':'no-cache'},
     })
      .success(function(data) {
           if(data.result==1)
               return true;
           else
               return false;
          })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         location.reload();
    });
};
```

I need to do form validation and form submit only if the "checkLogin" returns true. ie **data.result==1**. So that if data.result==1 then it will validate the form and submit

can anyone please give me an idea abot how to alter "$scope.formSubmit"

Comment: Process is backwards. Why would you not check login status before form needs to be presented? Also why are you using `jQuery` to get value and not using data model? ***NEVER*** use `async:   false` ... it is deprecated and a terrible practice. Look at the warnings it is throwing in your console

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `$asyncValidators`

From the Docs:

> ### Custom Validation
>
> Additionally, there is the `$asyncValidators` object which handles asynchronous validation, such as making an `$http` request to the backend. Functions added to the object must return a promise that must be `resolved` when valid or `rejected` when invalid. In-progress async validations are stored by key in [ngModelController.$pending](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$pending).

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)